# Communicate with Serial Ports from different ApiController instances in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, serial-port

What I Need:
I am trying to expose an API in C# using .NET that will allow users to control motor drivers connected to the computer hosting the server via Serial Port communication.

My Problem:
I'm not quite sure how to allow multiple ApiController class instances to communicate with (potentially the same) Serial Port(s)

***I know I need to use the SerialPort class, that's not the issue I'm having***

My Thoughts:
I'm thinking that this will have to be done via a shared class between all of the different controllers, i.e. my SteeringWheelMainTelescopeMotorController will need to read/write data from/to a specific device on a Serial Port, while my SteeringWheelTiltMotorController will need to read/write data from/to that same device on the same Serial Port (The motor driver I'm using supports control of multiple motors).

Any help would be really appreciated!

***I'm not worried about concurrency issues, only one user will be using the API at a time***

Comment: Your question, as is, isn't really a good for SO. I can tell you that you'll want to use the [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class though.

Comment: Sorry, should be more clear, I know how to instantiate SerialPort communication, what I'm not sure how to do is set it up in a way that I can perform write commands when my API is triggered (from potentially multiple different controllers)

Comment: Even if you get this working, you're going to have real trouble with concurrency. What happens when two people request the same action at the same time?

Comment: @DavidG in my particular case this won't be an issue. Only one client will ever be interacting with the API at a time.

Comment: @BrianCorbin Are you still looking for an answer to this? I may be able to provide one later on today.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so as an electrical engineer who works with software involving C# and serial ports almost every day, here is some advice that I can offer you from an architectural perspective.

1. **Use this architecture in the situation where you need to control the motors across several application domains.** Have some process/service running in the background that controls your port 100% of the time (via your API). You can launch an application then talk to the background service (responsible for controlling the motor) via TCP sockets. This way you can launch as many applications as you want and everybody will get access to the API without having to worry about serial port access issues.
2. **Use this architecture in the situation where you need to control the motors in a single application domain.** This one's similar to what you're already proposing in your question, which by the way I think is a pretty good way of doing things. Instantiate the class to control the motors from your API and then use constructor/property injection, or some kind of DI to pass a reference to the controller to everybody who needs it.

Comment: Thanks, Snoopy! I've been working on this project for a week now, and I've learned a ton so far. I decided to go with a static service for controlling all of the different devices from my API, and just running any commands I need to send to them in background threads. It seems to be working really well, and the result is even cooler (I can control motors over the web, so cool). Thanks for the tips, definitely helpful!

Comment: @BrianCorbin No problem, sounds like a cool project. If there's anything else I can help with let me know.

Comment: @BrianCorbin The more I think about this problem, the more I think you could almost use something like WCF to isolate an API for controlling the motors over serial... then you can talk to that service via IPC. Look into using WCF.

Answer (score 0):

So I defined a IMotorPort interface which includes async methods for sending and receiving to a motor, and would establish the SerialPort in it encapsulation. The MotorPort class would then handle issues such as converting the string commands (or even better a DTO) to the Motor. Also this would be the place to insert a queing mechanism to handle concurrent requests which I would recommend doing now rather than later just to be safe.

Then your controllers would take a IMotorPort in their constructors and your bootstrapper would insure they are of the same instance.

```
public interface IMotorPort
{
   Task SendData(string data);
   Task<string> RecieveData();
}
public class MotorPort : IMotorPort
{
   protected SerialPort Port{get;set;}
   public Task SendData(string data)
   {
    //TODO: Send from Serial Port
   }
   public Task<string> RecieveData()
   {
    //TODO: Recieve from Serial Port
   }
 }
 public class SteeringWheelMainTelescopeMotorController
{
   protected IMotorPort Motor{get;set;}
   public SteeringWheelMainTelescopeMotorController(IMotorPort motor)
   {
       this.Motor = motor;
    }
 }
 public class SteeringWheelTiltMotorController
 {
   protected IMotorPort Motor{get;set;}
   public SteeringWheelTiltMotorController(IMotorPort motor)
   {
      this.Motor = motor;
   }
}
```